# Cleanup work in Scala or Java

Tags: scala, inheritance

Suppose I have 2 classes, with inheritance

```
abstract class A {
  val a = /* some resource */
}

class B extends A {
  /* consume resource a */

  /*
   * then close resource a
   */
  a.close
}
```

Resource `a` cannot be closed before it is consumed in the subclasses, however, I wish to not having to write the closing statement all over the subclasses.

Do you know what trick I can use for this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way will be to define "resource" in class A as the function that takes consumer function, calls it with actual resource argument and closes resource afterwards.

```
  abstract class A {
    def a(consumer: Resource => Unit) = {
      val r = new Resource
      consumer(r)
      r.close()
    }
  }

  class B extends A {
    a { resource =>
      resource.consume()
    }
  }
```

However, this approach has several drawbacks:

- If there are more then one resource, code that need to work with all resources at once will require nested braces, which is kinda ugly
- If class that extends `B` wants to work with the resource which is already used in `B` then such resource will be opened/closed two times